# Upgrade Cucumber 2.4 -> 4.0 failed: cannot load such file -- cucumber/core/gherkin/tag_expression (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Upgrading cucumber framework from 2.4 to 4.0 and running into an issue:

```
Start Test Suite [ 2019-02-14 13:15:40 -0800 ]
Selenium standalone isn't running. Starting standalone server in background.
Determining host operating system... darwin18.2.0
Determining host operating system... darwin18.2.0
cannot load such file -- cucumber/core/gherkin/tag_expression (LoadError)
SITE_TYPE: desktop  DEBUG_MODE: false  SELENIUM_ENV: local  SELENIUM BROWSER: firefox  RERUN_TEST: false
quitting browser
End Test Suite [ 2019-02-14 13:15:42 -0800 ]
```

Can't launch any test with or without tags, would appreciate if anyone can share some ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tag_expression` is moved into another gem: called [`cucumber-tag_expressions`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/tag-expressions), as mentioned [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1328#issuecomment-442944592). Depending on where this error is raised in the code you might need to change the `require` which raises the error or you might just need to install the gem.

Another thing that I noticed is that Cucumber 4.0 is still in RC (Release Candidate), not in stable yet, so you might want to revert to the latest stable version, which is 3.1.2 as of today, which possibly will fix the issue.